# Как правильно пользоваться Phonegap?

Tags: phonegap, cordova, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Пишу приложение "Hello World" (html, css). Установил Phonegap, компилю через build.phonegap.com. Закидываю в телефон - работает. Теперь вопрос.

1. Как написать приложение с помощью Phonegap и организовать его работу так, как работает мой сайт сейчас? То есть имею админку, там что то меняю, изменения видны на сайте (новости, фото, новые страницы, что угодно). Так и в приложении, меняю на сервере -> видно в приложении, и всё это на Phonegap, как это сделать? (или нужно постоянно компилить с изменениями)
2. Есть необходимость создать приложение, структура примерна такова:
   Категории (авто, рестораны, кафе), в каждой категории по 5-10 страниц (заведений), в каждой странице (заведении) текст + картинки. Есть ли готовая сборка или может метод как создать такое приложение наименьшими усилиями? (web знаю хорошо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При изменении чего-то в админке сайта в вебе изменения сохраняются в базу данных, поэтому перегонять именно сайт в приложение смысла нет.
Из вариантов - сделать iframe или что-то подобное, поверх него доделать менюшку для роутинга и работать с ней.
По пункту 2 сборки нет, но есть `ionic`. Почитайте, должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо. По первому пункту меня интересует сама логика с обновлением. Как делать, грубо говоря, sql update?

Comment: Или через выделенное апи сервера, которые вы сами пишете, или через админку сайта, загружаемую через iframe

Comment: Ну я так понимаю что приложение таким же способом связывается с базой как и сайт? php? Не понятно что за iframe вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Html тэг <ifrane>. Приложение может состоять только из javascript, и не может выполнять php код локально. Только слать запросы к php коду на сервере сайта

Comment: Чтобы не создавать новую тему, хочу спросить у Вас. К примеру я создал приложение на Ionic. Оно представляет собой набор страниц с информацией, как я описывал выше: "Категории (авто, рестораны, кафе), в каждой категории по 5-10 страниц (заведений), в каждой странице (заведении) текст + картинки. " Как приложению получить обновления? Как организовать админку? Сориентируйте пожалуйста. К примеру я хочу добавить еще одно заведение в категорию Кафе, нужно будет перезаливать приложение в магазин?